# Load entities before response in jax-rs

Tags: jpa, jax-rs

There is a way to response a Entity in jax-rs without load subentities? Because when I try to generate a response using a JPA 2 Entity I get the follow error:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: mypackage.Project.tags, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->mypackage.Project["tags"])
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_PROJECT"
public class Project {      

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="COD_PROJECT")
    private String codProject;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="COD_PROJECT")
    private List<Tag> tags;

}
```

My response:

```
@Path("/projects")
public class ConsultaSolicFomentoResource {


    @Context 
    private HttpServletRequest requestContext;  

    @EJB
    private ProjectServiceLocal projectServiceLocal;

    @GET
    @Path("/list") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response listProjects() {
        List<Project> projects = projectServiceLocal.listProjects();
        return Response.ok(projects).build(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo may need to return DTOs instead of the actual Business/doamin entities in the Response. 
Your list of ProjectDTO instances would be initialized from the returned projects and only the attributes that you want to return to the client would be copied into the DTO.